# Custom MVC routing - limiting routes

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller, routes

I have created my custom MVC framework in PHP, but i'm new to PHP and to Apatche so i don't know how to make good routing system going.

For now i have only some default options set in .htaccess files, but this does not redirect paths not used in my application. You can paste http://localhost/myapp/whatever and it will take you to main page, but from this point every link click breaks application.

What i want to do is to redirect to home/index every route not used in my app. Is there any way to do this with .htaccess files? Or should i create Router class to handle this problem?

I tried .htaccess but i don't get how this works and the only thing i achieved was to remove word public from url so my url looks cleaner.

Here's my .htaccess file on path ./public/:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /myapp/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ ../index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Next to this file i have my index.php:

```
<?php
use core\App;

require_once '../app/init.php';

$app = new App;
```

I also have this .htaccess file on app root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

I tried some of ChatGPT suggestions, but most of the time app ended up with iternal errors etc.
Now i want to do something like Router class that will know all "good" routes and will redirect all "bad" routes to home/index, but i don't know if this is good approach.

Comment: Where is your code? what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'll update my post, give me a minute.